# All whitespaces are matched in man

Tags: regular-expression, man

In WSL-Ubuntu 18.04 with Bash 4.4.20(1) and `man` with `less` I ran inside `man grep` the command `-o,|`  aiming to match an -o with a comma or with a whitespace after it.

But, instead, *all whitespaces in the document* were matched, why is that and how could I match only an -o with a comma or a whitespace after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a regular expression, `"-o,| "` matches on either `"-o,"` or `" "`.

Use `-o(,| )` or `-o[, ]` to match on `-o` followed by either `,` or space. Or `-o\>` for a `-o` that is not followed by a *word character* (*word characters* being either underscore or characters classified as alnum in the locale).

Instead of using `man`, you could use `info`. `info` manuals, especially for GNU software (such as the `grep` implementation found on Ubuntu) are generally more complete, and more importantly here have a searchable table of contents and index.

It makes it easier to jump to specific topics in the documentation.

For instance, with:

```
info -- grep -o
```

You'll jump directly to the description of the `-o` option.

Within `info`, you can also press <kbd>i</kbd> to bring up the index (and enter `-o` there with <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion), or <kbd>I</kbd> (uppercase `i`) to get a list of index entries for a given search string.

Beware however that on some systems, even GNU ones such as Debian/Ubuntu, documentation in `info` format is sometimes not installed by default. You may need to install some `somesoftware-doc` package to get the documentation of `somesoftware` in `info` format.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching `-o,` or space. 
You want to match `-o` followed by `,` or space. 
Try `-o(,| )`.